# Dataframe Sum contiguous columns following Duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I have one df dataframe as follow :

```
     Item   Size
0   .decash    1
1   .decash    2
2    usdjpy    1
3   .decash    1
4    usdjpy    1
```

I would to transform to a df2 as follow (drop duplicates and sum Size) :

```
     Item   Size
0   .decash    4
1    usdjpy    2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `groupby(..., as_index=False)` and `sum()`:

```
In [270]: df.groupby('Item', as_index=False)['Size'].sum()
Out[270]:
      Item  Size
0  .decash     4
1   usdjpy     2
```